# Console application via MPI .Net crashes with FileNotFoundException

Tags: .net, windows, mpi

I'm trying to run my simple .Net console app with the MPI.Net package. I have the following exception:

```
"Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MPI, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=29b4a045737654fe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'MPI, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=29b4a045737654fe'
   at MPIProject.Program.Main(String[] args)"
```

This I have on every process launched

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MPI;

namespace MPIProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (new MPI.Environment(ref args))
            {
                if (MPI.Environment.Finalized)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Communicator.world.Rank);
                }
                
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. A library is missing. [Have you followed the instructions?](https://github.com/mpidotnet/MPI.NET#building-on-windows) What are. you trying to do anyway? .NET offers built-in libraries for data parallelism (Parallel, PLINQ), agents and message passing (TPL Dataflow, Channels), asynchronous operations (async/await), and low lever concurrent operations with Tasks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar exception to this while I was trying to run the [PingPong example program](https://github.com/microsoft/MPI.NET/blob/master/Examples/PingPong/PingPong.cs) in the MPI.NET repository.  I ended up doing this:

- Making a new Console App project in Visual Studio
- Adding the MPI.NET nuget package (by right-clicking the project in the solution explorer, selecting "Manage NuGet Packages", and then searching for "MPI.NET")
- Copying the example program into my main class.

After that, the program worked.  I imagine there's something wrong with a reference in the metadata that the repository has stored with the project.